# Efficient "linking" of two GIT repositories (open and closed source)

Tags: git, repository

For my next dual licensed open source project I would like to use Git for the first time.

Assume that in the development environment my project consists of a `src` and a `doc` directory, which contain all open source files, so that they should be available in a public Git repository.

```
XYZ/
   |-doc public
   |-src public
      |-main public
      |-test public
   |-internal
      |-int1 commercial/internal
      |-int2 commercial/internal
```

I want to be able to keep the complete folder structure (public and internal files) in a 'private' repository, and 'update' a public Git repository with changes except for the `internal` folder.

**Is there a recommended solution to have a part of the working copy be in two Git repositories at the same time?**

In this example, all folders marked as 'public' would need to be in both the private and the public repository, so that I can propagate changes for a file in both directions.

Comment: You could checkout what `git submodule` offers

Comment: @J.J.Hakala if I use submodules, can I create a working copy of the whole project for an old revision and it will use the submodule version which was present then?

Comment: Yes, that's exactly what submodules do. The main project references a specific commit of the submodule.